# Is it possible to use argparse to capture an arbitrary set of optional arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to use `argparse` to capture an arbitrary set of optional arguments?

For example both the following should be accepted as inputs:

```
python script.py required_arg1 --var1 value1 --var2 value2 --var3 value3

python script.py required_arg1 --varA valueA --var2 value2 --varB valueB
```

*a priori* I don't know what optional arguments would be specified receive but would handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is kind of a hackish way, but it works well:

Check, which arguments are not added and add them

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("foo")
parser.add_argument("-bar", type=int)
# parser can have any arguments, whatever you want!

parsed, unknown = parser.parse_known_args() # this is an 'internal' method
# which returns 'parsed', the same as what parse_args() would return
# and 'unknown', the remainder of that
# the difference to parse_args() is that it does not exit when it finds redundant arguments

for arg in unknown:
    if arg.startswith(("-", "--")):
        # you can pass any arguments to add_argument
        parser.add_argument(arg.split('=')[0], type=<your type>, ...)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

For example:

```
python3 arbitrary_parser.py ha -bar 12 -extra1 value1 -extra2 value2
```

Then the result would be

```
args = Namespace(bar=12, foo='ha', extra1='value1' extra2='value2')
```

Comment: One of the earlier answers used `parse_known_args`, but then used the `sys.argv` style of parsing for the `unknown`.  I like your idea of adding those flags to the parser, and re-parsing.  Hackish requirements require hackish solutions. :)

Comment: thank you a stack @MrP01 this is a perfectly clean way of using the interface. And lets us still do filtering for badly formed arbitrary args in one place.

Answer (score 4):

Possible?  possibly, but I wouldn't recommend it.  `argparse` is the not best tool for parsing this kind of input, or conversely, this a poor argument specification from an `argparse` perspective.

Have you thought about what the `usage` line should look like?  How would explain this to your users?

How would you parse this working from `sys.argv` directly?  It looks like you could collect 3 pieces:

```
 prog = sys.argv[0]
 arg1 = sys.argv[1]
 keys = sys.argv[2::2]
 # maybe strip -- off each
 values = sys.argv[3::2]
 kvdict = {k:v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
```

There are other SO questions asking about generic `key:value` pairs.  Things like:

```
 --args key1:value1 key2:value2
```

This can be handled with `nargs='*'` and an action that splits each input string on `:` (or `=`) and stores things by `key`.

Your requirement is least amenable to `argparse` use because it requires bypassing the whole idea of matching argument flags with strings in `argv`.  It requires, some how, turning off all the normal `argparse` parsing.

Looks like I suggested the same thing a couple of years ago

[Parse non-pre-defined argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920989/parse-non-pre-defined-argument)

or earlier

[Using argparse to parse arguments of form "arg= val"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154716/using-argparse-to-parse-arguments-of-form-arg-val)