# Python parse_known_args with named arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to pass an arbitrary set of arguments in the format `--arg1 value1` to my python script and retrieve them in a dictionary of the kind `{'arg1': 'value1}`. I want to use `argparse` to achieve that. The function `parse_known_args` allows for extra args, but they can be retrieved as a simple list and are not named.

Comment: you can simply define the option using the `add_argument` method.  `parse_known_args` is a method that will parse all the options defined via `add_argument` and return the remaining command line, while using `parse_args` will raise an error if there are left over arguments.

Comment: The extra arguments can be of any name/value, not known a priori.

Comment: Then `argparse` has no chance of knowing what to do with it. That is the point of `parse_known_args`: **you** have to manually handle the remaining arguments as you please.

Comment: Alternatively you could change your syntax from `--arg value` to something like `--define arg value` and define a custom `Action` that will do what you want.

Comment: I see your point. My idea was mainly to have a cmd line syntax like `... --arg1 val1` and `argparse` would make a dictionary like `extra_args = {"arg1": "val1"}`. But I guess there is no such option and I have to build the dictionary myself.

Answer (score 2):

A better idea is to define *one* option that takes two arguments, a name and a value, and use a custom action to update a dictionary using those two arguments.

```
class OptionAppend(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        d = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        name, value = values
        d[name] = value

p.add_argument("-o", "--option", nargs=2, action=OptionAppend, default={})
```

Then instead of `myscript --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2`, you would write `myscript -o arg1 value1 -o arg2value1`, and after `args = parser.parse_args()`, you would have `args.o == {'arg1': 'value1, 'arg2': 'value2'}`.

---

This is somewhat analogous to the use of a list or dictionary to hold a set of related variables, instead of a set of individually named variables.

```
 # Good
 v = [x, y, z]
 v = { 'key1': x, 'key2': y, 'key3': z}
 # Bad
 v1 = x
 v2 = y
 v3 = z
```

Answer (score 0):

The question of handling arbitrary key/value pairs has come up a number of times.  `argparse` does not have a builtin mechanism for that.

[Is it possible to use argparse to capture an arbitrary set of optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367331/argparse-arbitrary-optional-arguments)  (almost a duplicate from last May)

Your idea of using `parse_know_args` and then doing your own dictionary build from the `extras` is good - and perhaps the simplest.  How you handle the extras list will depend on how well behaved your users are (predicable `'--key', 'value'` pairs).  This basically the same as if you parsed `sys.arv[1:]` directly.

If the user gives input like `--options key1:value1 key2=value2 "key3 value3"` you can parse those pairs in a custom Action class (e.g. split the string on the delimiter etc).

Input like `--options "{key1: value1, key2: value2}"` can be handled as a `JSON` string, with a type function like: `type=json.load` (I'd have to look that up).