# Support arbitrary number of related named arguments with Python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to support a command line interface where users can declare an arbitrary number of samples, with one or more input files corresponding to each sample. Something like this:

```
$ myprogram.py \
      --foo bar \
      --sample1 input1.tsv \
      --sample2 input2a.tsv input2b.tsv input2c.tsv \
      --sample3 input3-filtered.tsv \
      --out output.tsv
```

The idea is that the option keys will match the pattern `--sample(\d+)`, and each key will consume all subsequent arguments as option values until the next `-` or `--` prefixed flag is encountered. For explicitly declared arguments, this is a common use case that the `argparse` module supports with the `nargs='+'` option. But since I need to support an arbitrary number of arguments I can't declare them explicitly.

The `parse_known_args` command will give me access to all user-supplied arguments, but those not explicitly declared will not be grouped into an indexed data structure. For these I would need to carefully examine the argument list, look ahead to see how many of the subsequent values correspond to the current flag, etc.

Is there any way I can parse these options without having to essentially re-implement large parts of an argument parser (almost) from scratch?

Comment: Have you considered building the argparser on the fly? Count the number of `--sample` you have on the command line and use that to build an appropriate argparser? Kind of roundabout, but it lets argparse do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with a slightly different syntax, namely:

```
$ myprogram.py \
  --foo bar \
  --sample input1.tsv \
  --sample input2a.tsv input2b.tsv input2c.tsv \
  --sample input3-filtered.tsv \
  --out output.tsv
```

where the parameter name doesn't contain a number, but still it performs grouping, try this:

```
parser.add_argument('--sample', action='append', nargs='+')
```

It produces a list of lists, ie. `--sample x y --sample 1 2` will produce `Namespace(sample=[['x', 'y'], ['1', '2']])`

Comment: I've used `action="append"` before, but never in this context. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to make that number or key at separate argument value, and collect the related arguments in an nested list.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--out')
parser.add_argument('--sample', nargs='+', action='append', metavar=('KEY','TSV'))

parser.print_help()

argv = "myprogram.py \
      --foo bar \
      --sample 1 input1.tsv \
      --sample 2 input2a.tsv input2b.tsv input2c.tsv \
      --sample 3 input3-filtered.tsv \
      --out output.tsv"
argv = argv.split()
args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
print(args)
```

produces:

```
1031:~/mypy$ python3 stack44267794.py -h
usage: stack44267794.py [-h] [--foo FOO] [--out OUT] [--sample KEY [TSV ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO
  --out OUT
  --sample KEY [TSV ...]
Namespace(foo='bar', out='output.tsv', 
    sample=[['1', 'input1.tsv'], 
            ['2', 'input2a.tsv', 'input2b.tsv', 'input2c.tsv'], 
            ['3', 'input3-filtered.tsv']])
```

There have been questions about collecting general `key:value` pairs. There's nothing in `argparse` to directly support that.  Various things have been suggested, but all boil down to parsing the pairs yourself.

[Is it possible to use argparse to capture an arbitrary set of optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367331/is-it-possible-to-use-argparse-to-capture-an-arbitrary-set-of-optional-arguments)

You have added the complication that the number of arguments per key is variable.  That rules out handling '--sample1=input1' as simple strings.

`argparse` has extended a well known `POSIX` commandline standard.  But if you want to move beyond that, then be prepared to process the arguments either before (sys.argv) or after `argparse` (the `parse_known_args` `extras`).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment:

```
import argparse

argv = "myprogram.py \
      --foo bar \
      --sample1 input1.tsv \
      --sample2 input2a.tsv input2b.tsv input2c.tsv \
      --sample3 input3-filtered.tsv \
      --out output.tsv"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--out')
for x in range(1, argv.count('--sample') + 1):
    parser.add_argument('--sample' + str(x), nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args(argv.split()[1:])
```

Gives:

```
print args
Namespace(foo='bar', out='output.tsv', sample1=['input1.tsv'], sample2=['input2a.tsv', 'input2b.tsv', 'input2c.tsv'], sample3=['input3-filtered.tsv'])
```

With the real `sys.argv` you'll probably have to replace the `argv.count` with the slightly longer `' '.join(sys.argv).count('--sample')`

The major downside to this approach is the auto help generation will not cover these fields.

Comment: Your  code works with a string `argv`, but not with the already split `sys.argv`.  The help will list any `sample#` that are also given in the commandline, along with the '-h'.  But to show a generic `sample#` you'd have to use a custom `usage` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It may well be possible to do the sort of thing that you are looking for with [click](https://github.com/pallets/click) rather than `argparse`.

To quote:

> $ click_
>
> Click is a Python package for creating beautiful command line
>   interfaces   in a composable way with as little code as necessary. 
>   It's the "Command   Line Interface Creation Kit".  It's highly
>   configurable but comes with   sensible defaults out of the box.
>
> It aims to make the process of writing command line tools quick and
>   fun   while also preventing any frustration caused by the inability to
>   implement   an intended CLI API.
>
> Click in three points:
>
> - arbitrary nesting of commands
> - automatic help page generation
> - supports lazy loading of subcommands at runtime
>
>   Read the docs at http://click.pocoo.org/

One of the important features of click is the ability to construct sub-commands, (a bit like using git or image magic covert), which should allow you to structure your command line as:

```
myprogram.py \
  --foo bar \
  --sampleset input1.tsv \
  --sampleset input2a.tsv input2b.tsv input2c.tsv \
  --sampleset input3-filtered.tsv \
  combinesets --out output.tsv
```

Or even:

```
myprogram.py \
  --foo bar \
  process input1.tsv \
  process input2a.tsv input2b.tsv input2c.tsv \
  process input3-filtered.tsv \
  combine --out output.tsv
```

Which might be cleaner, in this case your code would have parameters called `--foo` and `--out` and functions called `process` and `combine` process would be called with the input file(s) specified and combine with no parameters.

Comment: Unless you can actually show how to do this with click — or at least indicate what features to use — this doesn't really count as an answer.