# argparse a pattern of arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, argparse

I need to have a command line in the form

```
python script.py --step1=100 --step3=53 --step2=34
```

The requirements are

- I don't know how many `--stepN` flags there are in advance
- The order of the `--stepN` flags are not set, so I cannot just use `action='append'`

I'm also interested in these restrictions too:

- The step numbers should be continuous, so if `--step20` is used but `--step19` is missing, this is an error.
- I want the destination of the values in one list. So in the above command line example, I want to do something like

```py
args = parser.parse_args()
args.steps # is list [100, 34, 53]
```

Can `argparse` take a pattern of agruments, and somehow I can write a custom  action or type to do what I want? I'm thinking something like

```
parser.add_argument('--step*',
                    type=CustomType,
                    action=CustomAction,
                    help='Use --step1=a --step2=b, ....')
```

Comment: You can pass a dictionary based on your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good `argparse` fit.  There have been a number of questions about accepting generalized `key=value` inputs, and various kludgey answers.  For the most part the answers amount to parsing the strings yourself, either from `sys.argv` or the `extras` of `parse_known_args`.

[Create variable key/value pairs with argparse (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146262/create-variable-key-value-pairs-with-argparse-python)

This is doubly true with your added requirements about the form of the key.

In the latest such question I suggested using `append` and `nargs=2` so the input would be of the form:

```
python script.py --step 1 100 --step 2 53 --step 3 34
```

producing

```
Namespace(step=[[1,100], [2,53], [3, 24]])
```

which you could process and value check to your heart's content.

[Support arbitrary number of related named arguments with Python argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267794/support-arbitrary-number-of-related-named-arguments-with-python-argparse)