# How to make argparse treat all arguments as positional?

Tags: python, argparse, positional-argument

How can I make an [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) parser treat all arguments as *positional*, even the ones that look like options? For example, with this definition:

```
parser.add_argument('cmd', nargs='*', help='The command to run')
```

I want to be able to run

```
prog.py mycomand --foo arg
```

and have `['mycomand', '--foo', 'arg']` be captured as the `cmd` argument.

Comment: Why not use `sys.argv[1:]` if you want to capture everything?

Comment: The program actually uses a lot of subparsers (to support subcommands), so I need `argparse`.

Comment: Can you use the [answer described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367331/is-it-possible-to-use-argparse-to-capture-an-arbitrary-set-of-optional-arguments) or do you need the parent parser to resolve well

Comment: REMAINDER and -- can be used to force interpreting the remaining arguments as positional.  See the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I just needed to replace `nargs='*'` with `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> `argparse.REMAINDER` All the remaining command-line arguments are gathered into a list. This is commonly useful for command line utilities that dispatch to other command line utilities.

This also works, but is less convenient:

```
prog.py mycomand -- --foo arg
```